# How to edit and save Microsoft word Document in iOS stored in local directory?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, dropbox

I am working with Dropbox and Microsoft word. I am able to download file from Dropbox and stored in local storage (in Document directory). Now i want to edit word document. I have tried couple of way but its not working for me.

Downloaded in local storage and open with Microsoft word using `UIDocumentInteractionController` but its opens read only copy and save in   Microsoft word app:

```
let file = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("/\(filename)")
// Do whatever you want with the document
self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: file)
self.docController.delegate = self
self.docController.presentOpenInMenu(from: self.view.frame, in: self.view, animated: true)
```

Download in local storage and open with Microsoft word using the URL schemes for Microsoft word app but its fails with error Can't open file :

```
let url : NSString = "ms-word:ofe|u|\(directoryContents[0])|z|yes|a|App" as NSString
let urlStr : NSString = url.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as NSString
let searchURL : NSURL = NSURL(string: urlStr as String)!
UIApplication.shared.openURL(searchURL as URL)
```

[image]

Directly download file (Using Dropbox share link) in word app using the URL schemes for Microsoft word app but its fails with error Can't open file   :

```
let url : NSString = "ms-word:ofv|u|https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxxxxx/new.docx?dl=0|p|xxxxxx|z|yes|a|App" as NSString
let urlStr : NSString = url.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as NSString
let searchURL : NSURL = NSURL(string: urlStr as String)!
UIApplication.shared.openURL(searchURL as URL)
```

[image]
[image]

I know this is because of iOS Sandboxing. It is not allowed to share data across the app. I don't want to use Dropbox app to edit the file and update it?

**Is there any way to download word file from Dropbox and edit in-app or using Microsoft word app?**

Comment: The issue downloading from the www.dropbox.com/s/... link may be because the `dl=0` version gives you a preview page, not the file. You should use `dl=1` instead, as [documented here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download). Note that this will still only give you the file data, and not a way to re-upload an edited version.

Comment: If you want to be able to download and upload files from/to Dropbox, you may want to use [the Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) instead.

Comment: @Greg I am able to download and upload file to Dropbox but i want to edit file after download. Similar functionality which is provided by Dropbox app for Microsoft word files.

Comment: Hi @SidMhatre did you come up a solution on how to edit a word file from the app?

Comment: @PepengHapon Nope. Downloading file  and it is available in read only option in word app.